# "Type 'ValidatorFn | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'." contact-form component in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a contact form in Angular but I get an error in my contact-form.ts that I simply can't understand. Here is my code :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
})
export class ContactFormComponent implements OnInit {

  FormData: FormGroup | undefined;

  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.FormData = this.builder.group ({
      Fullname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      Email: new FormControl('', [Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])]),
      Comment: new FormControl ('', [Validators.required])
    })
  }
}
```

the line that is causing me trouble is the following :

```js
Email: new FormControl('', [Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])])
```

I get told

> Type 'ValidatorFn | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.ts(2322)

Thank you!

Comment: Is [Validators.compose meant to be inside array brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Validators.compose()](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#compose) will return the value of `ValidatorFn` or `null`.

> static compose(validators: null): null

You hit this error as you enable strict type checking (`strict: true`) in tsconfig.json.

Would say that you don't need to use `Validators.compose()`, but use **an array (`ValidatorFn[]`)** for multiple validation checks as below:

```js
this.FormData = this.builder.group ({
  Email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  ...
})
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tg28ae?file=src/app/contact-form/contact-form.component.ts)